# Integer-based (K,N) indexing of Multi-Index DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

Say I have a sorted Multi-Index Dataframe:

```
color  food      one        two
green  ham   0.565738  1.545659
       eggs -0.974236 -0.070345
red    eggs  1.033801 -2.400454
       ham  -0.785435  0.462060
       pork  0.704228  0.523508

...
```

How can I retrieve **all elements** associated with the **Kth value** for the **1st level**. For example, if `K=2`, we would retrieve:

```
red    eggs  1.033801 -2.400454
       ham  -0.785435  0.462060
       pork  0.704228  0.523508
```

More generally, what is the syntax for `iloc` for Multi-level DataFrames?

### Update:

See this ticket on GitHub for a follow-up on the topic: ["Awkward" Integer-indexing in MultiIndex DataFrames](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/6629)

Comment: Thanks @Jeff - I honestly have tried with many combinations, and, assuming `k=1`, neither `df.iloc[1]` or `df.xs(1)` give me what I want. `df.iloc[1]` returns only one row, and `df.xs(1)` returns with `KeyError`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you are looking for all rows associated with the **Kth** value on your **Nth** level:

```
df.xs(df.index.levels[N][K], level=N)
```

Comment: This is **not** a robust way to do this, it raises for me for most K and N.

Comment: good point, you need to pass the level param to xs and then it should work. i edited the answer.

Comment: @AndyHayden Is the new solution (after the edits) "kosher" in Pandas? It would be great to hear your thoughts on this. I have also added an update to the OP.

Comment: I still don't think I'd do this, too easy to get index errors :S

Comment: @andy sorry i'm late on this, but could you give me an example? it just seems like this should work all the time if used correctly... and if not, no worries.

Comment: doesn't work if N > len(levels) or K > len(levels[N]), works if you know these in advance...

Answer (score 3):

[The indexing docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html) are pretty complete,  it pays to read and experiment:

Select by label

```
In [18]: df.loc[['green']]
Out[18]: 
                 one       two
green ham   0.261355  0.182691
      eggs  0.243253 -0.360223

[2 rows x 2 columns]
```

You can directly index with iloc if you want

```
In [24]: df.iloc[0:2]
Out[24]: 
                 one       two
green ham   0.261355  0.182691
      eggs  0.243253 -0.360223

[2 rows x 2 columns]
```

This will give you at most the kth (in this case 2) values for each of the values on level=0

```
In [35]: df.groupby(level=0).head(2)
Out[35]: 
                 one       two
green ham   0.261355  0.182691
      eggs  0.243253 -0.360223
red   eggs -0.147635  0.555402
      ham   1.815182  0.158497

[4 rows x 2 columns]
```

Here is the nth value (k-1); if a group doesn't have one nothing will be returned for that key

```
In [36]: df.groupby(level=0).nth(2)
Out[36]: 
               one       two
red pork -0.158261 -0.963434

[1 rows x 2 columns]

In [37]: df.groupby(level=0).nth(1)
Out[37]: 
                 one       two
green eggs  0.243253 -0.360223
red   ham   1.815182  0.158497

[2 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: Jeff - I would like to index using `k`, not the value of the index at that position. In other words, I am looking to use something along the lines of `iloc` here. I left a comment on the OP.

Comment: Jeff - your second answer assumes that I know how many values I have on the second level at index `k` of the first level. When indexing with a random `k`, I don't know that.

Comment: No, this has nothing to do with the level. I'll put up another way.

Comment: Thanks - Your third answer is close - it gives at most `k` entries, while I am only looking for the `kth` entry.

Comment: lots of ways to skin this cat

Comment: Thanks - although I would dare say that the only one that truly does the job is the last one.

Comment: On this note - it surprises me that `loc['label'] ` retrieves **all** entries on subsequent levels, but `iloc[k]` only returns **one**.

Comment: your specifcation by using 'label' hits a multi-index, and it assumes the 0th level so it give you what you asked for, iloc on the other hand doesn't care about indexes so it gives you a single entry. pandas tries to be 'smart' (sometimes can be too clever though)